# Python 3.3 C string handling (wchar_t vs char)

Tags: python, c++, c, api, python-3.x

I'm trying to embed Python 3.3 in our C++ project.
Python 3.3 seems to have introduced UTF-8 as preferred storage, [PEP 393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/): "the specification chooses UTF-8 as the recommended way of exposing strings to C code."

I wrote this initialization code, which seems to be simple and intuitive:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "log.h"

void python_init(const char *program_name) {
    if (not Py_IsInitialized()) {
        Py_SetProgramName(program_name);
        Py_Initialize();
        const char *py_version = Py_GetVersion();
        log::msg("initialized python %s", py_version);
    }
}
```

but compiling it fails:

```
/home/jj/devel/openage/src/engine/python.cpp:13:3: error: no matching function for call to 'Py_SetProgramName'
                Py_SetProgramName(program_name);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.3/pythonrun.h:25:18: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char *' to 'wchar_t *' for 1st argument
PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(wchar_t *);
                 ^
```

So yeah, obviously I need a `wchar_t *` here, but I don't see any reason why `char *` would not do the job here.

What is the best practice here?
Convert `char *` to `wchar *` and deal with locales ([mbstowcs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/)), which would also introduce unnecessary dynamic memory allocs?

Also, if Python decided to go for `wchar` entirely, why does `Py_GetVersion()` return a `char *` as I expected it?

I found a [similar question for Python <3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245140/how-do-you-use-the-python3-c-api-for-a-command-line-driven-app) , but I hope Python 3.3 is different (PEP 393?).

The code has to be cross-platform capable.

=> What's a fast and efficient solution to pass C strings (`char *`) to Python 3.3?

Comment: Have you tried `char*` rather than `const char*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.5, `Py_DecodeLocale` can be used to do the conversion.

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html#c.Py_DecodeLocale

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert a sequence of strings to an array of WCHAR pointers
PYWINTYPES_EXPORT void PyWinObject_FreeWCHARArray(LPWSTR *wchars, DWORD str_cnt);
```

can you use this...?

Comment: this is not a function available in `/usr/include/python3.3`, I think it's Windows® specific.