# Install Python 3 Standard Library on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to write some C code on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) that will call a Python script.  The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) I've found indicate that I need to include the Standard Library in my C code via one of its headers (Python.h).  The library is needed to call the Python interpreter from the C code. The docs say...

> The Python installers for the Windows platform usually includes the
>   entire standard library and often also include many additional
>   components. For **Unix-like** operating systems Python is normally
>   provided as a collection of packages, so it may be necessary to use
>   the packaging tools provided with the operating system to obtain some
>   or all of the optional components.

I've tried searching for the library via *apt-get*, but, have come up empty.  I've also installed pip figuring I might find the library via that route.  I can't compile my code without the library.  Can someone point me to where/how I can get access to the library so that I can embed a Python script into my C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the example code (and forget about using python3) given [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) and save it in a file like pythonInC.c, you have to do [two things (vartecs answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory). First the example code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

2nd, the configuration steps (see below for dev3.x packages):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and add (you have to use python3.x whenever python2.7 is written here (see below))

```
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

to your gcc command. When I did (again "python3.x" and s. below)

```
user ~/stack $ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 pythonInC.c
user ~/stack $ ./a.out 
Today is Sun Jan 25 13:03:37 2015
```

on my raspberry running raspbian, I got the expected output as you can see.

However, coming back to python3. I have 3.2 here an did the steps analogue to the given above with 2.7 changed to 3.2. This gave me an error:

```
user ~/programming/stack $ gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.2 -lpython3.2 pythonInC.c 
pythonInC.c: In function 'main':
pythonInC.c:6:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Py_SetProgramName' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/python3.2/pythonrun.h:25:18: note: expected 'wchar_t *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is at least one discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245140/how-do-you-use-the-python3-c-api-for-a-command-line-driven-app), however I did not solve that yet to give here as an easy answer. But [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245140/how-do-you-use-the-python3-c-api-for-a-command-line-driven-app) might be solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped solve my problem.  Since I am using Geany on the Pi, I was able to set the compile and build configuration to point to the appropriate paths.  I am now able to compile my code.